# SQL Concatenating Cells of Same Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query capable of concatenating the values in the ProfileItemID column with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Here's the query. First of all, I'm not sure if it's right because I get this error after running it.

```
    SELECT RoomID, ',' + ProfileItemID 
    FROM RoomProfile
    WHERE RoomID = 1829 
    FOR XML PATH('')
```

"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int."

Attached is an image containing information I have of the table and images of the entire screen.

Hopefully, someone can please help me out. I really don't know what to do since I'm very new to SQL still.

Thank you in advance!

Table:

```
    |----------------------------------------|
    |                RoomProfile             |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |         RoomID      |   ProfileItemID  |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          1829       |         28       |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          1829       |         103      |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          1829       |         104      |
    |----------------------------------------|
```

Output:

```
    |----------------------------------------|
    |          1829       |   28, 103, 104   |
    |----------------------------------------|
```

[image: TABLE]
[image: Screenshot_1]
[image: Screenshot_2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenating a column within the same column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945974/concatenating-a-column-within-the-same-column-in-sql-server)

Comment: `CONCAT(RoomID, ',', ProfileItemID)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`STUFF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function and **[`FOR XML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)** clause with `PATH` mode as

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([RoomID] int, [ProfileItemID] int)
;

INSERT INTO T
    ([RoomID], [ProfileItemID])
VALUES
    (1829, 28),
    (1829, 103),
    (1829, 104);

SELECT DISTINCT RoomID,
       STUFF(
              (SELECT ',' + CAST(ProfileItemID AS VARCHAR(10))
               FROM T
               FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
       ) Result
FROM T;
```

**Returns:**

```
+--------+------------+
| RoomID |   Result   |
+--------+------------+
|   1829 | 28,103,104 |
+--------+------------+
```

**[Demo](https://rextester.com/SOBE83911)**

Comment: SELECT RoomID, ProfileItemID = 
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + cast(ProfileItemID AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM RoomProfile b 
WHERE b.RoomId = a.RoomiD FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM RoomProfile a 
Where RoomId = 1829
GROUP BY RoomID                                 <<<<<<< I take it back. Your answer was the right one to go by. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to convert the id to a string:

```
SELECT RoomID, ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ProfileItemID)
FROM RoomProfile
WHERE RoomID = 1829 
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: OP is still missing the `STUFF()` call that will format the results the way his Expected Output is.

Comment: Beside to what @digital.aaron say, I don't think `VARCHAR(MAX)` needed here cause _ProfileItemID_ datatype is `INT`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gordon's answer, you can use CAST function as well like below:

```
SELECT RoomID, ',' + Cast(ProfileItemID as varchar(50))
```

Comment: I don't think `VARCHAR(MAX)` needed here, cause _ProfileItemID_ datatype is `INT`.